# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous - simple for loop to fill empty array not working

Tags: python, pandas

The following is my code, where cities are pandas dataframes where the column I want is in the 6th column. I want to put the 6th column in each of these data frames into an empty numpy array but I keep getting the same error

`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The first bit is just me getting rid of the null values which works fine.

I know it would be easier just to not do this in a loop but I will be doing it over a larger number of cities further down the line.

```
cities = [perth,melbourne,brisbane]
rainfall = np.empty(((len(perth), len(cities))))

for i in cities:
    rainfall[:,cities.index(i)] = i.iloc[:,5]
```

Comment: Hey unable to reproduce the error can you please add information about the data to get more clarity??

Comment: @UjjwalAgrawal Hi, it is a 365 rows x 8 columns dataframe with product code, ID number, year, month, day, daily rainfall, number of days rainfall was measured, quality.

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony sorry, those lines were fine. It's only the last line, I've deleted the other lines now to avoid confusion

Comment: i['Rainfall amount (millimetres)'] = i['Rainfall amount (millimetres)'].replace(np.nan, 0)
If the Rainfall amount (millimetres) is not present how can you apply replace operation?